# R - Bind values from certain columns and selected rows and replacing them inside the group

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

I would like to create a new variable called `Var3` that combines the values of `Year` and `Month` from the row in which `Var1 == 1`. My data is grouped by `ID` (in long format). In cases without a 1 on `Var1` in any row (e.g. ID 3) there should be NA's on `Var3`.

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID    Var1   Year      Month
1      0      2008      2         
1      0      2009      2   
1      0      2010      2   
1      0      2011      2   
1      1      2013      2   
1      0      2014      10  
2      0      2008      2         
2      0      2010      2   
2      1      2011      2   
2      0      2013      2   
2      0      2015      11  
3      0      2010      2   
3      0      2011      2   
3      0      2013      2   
3      0      2015      11  
3      0      2017      10", header=TRUE)
```

My expected outcome would look like this:

```
df <- read.table(text=
"ID    Var1   Year      Month     Var2    
1      0      2008      2         20132     
1      0      2009      2         20132
1      0      2010      2         20132
1      0      2011      2         20132
1      1      2013      2         20132       
1      0      2014      10        20112
2      0      2008      2         20112      
2      0      2010      2         20112
2      1      2011      2         20112       
2      0      2013      2         20112
2      0      2015      11        20112
3      0      2010      2         NA
3      0      2011      2         NA
3      0      2013      2         NA    
3      0      2015      11        NA     
3      0      2017      10        NA",header=TRUE)
```

I am trying to figure out how to solve this issue using `dplyr`. I am pretty new to `tidyverse` therefore any suggestions are more than welcome. I already figured out that I have to use `group_by(ID)` and probably `mutate` to create the new variable. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using `dplyr` is

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Var3 = ifelse(Var1 == 1, paste0(Year, Month), NA)) %>%
  mutate(Var3 = max(Var3, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The idea behind it is: first, you paste together `Year` and `Month` where `Var1 == 1`, then *inside each group* you spread the only value present for `Var3` with a function such as `max` (but it could also be `min`) removing the NA values.

Output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID  Var1  Year Month Var3 
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
 1     1     0  2008     2 20132
 2     1     0  2009     2 20132
 3     1     0  2010     2 20132
 4     1     0  2011     2 20132
 5     1     1  2013     2 20132
 6     1     0  2014    10 20132
 7     2     0  2008     2 20112
 8     2     0  2010     2 20112
 9     2     1  2011     2 20112
10     2     0  2013     2 20112
11     2     0  2015    11 20112
12     3     0  2010     2 NA   
13     3     0  2011     2 NA   
14     3     0  2013     2 NA   
15     3     0  2015    11 NA   
16     3     0  2017    10 NA
```